# Is it possible for a modal view to not fill the entire screen on compact?

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, uikit, segue

I'd like to present a modal view for creating content in my app and I'd like a style like the iOS Mail app. When you compose a new email, it covers most of the screen except the top. I've tried multiple modal segue styles and all take up the full screen. I get this:
[image]

And I'd like something like this:
[image]

I've tried all the presentation styles. No code to share since so far this is just storyboarded.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ControllerForPresent: UIViewController {

var parentController: UIViewController!

func present(from parent: UIViewController) {
    parentController = parent
    parentController.view.superview!.backgroundColor = .black
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.addChildController(self)
    view.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    view.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 40
    UIView.animate(0.45, damping: 1, velocity: 1, options: .allowUserInteraction) {
        self.parentController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 40
    }
}

@objc private func close() {
    UIView.animate(0.3, animation: {
        self.parentController.view.transform = .identity
        self.view.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }, completion: {
        self.parentController.view.superview!.backgroundColor = .white
        self.removeFromParent()
    })
}
}

 class ControllerThatPresents: UIViewController {

     private func showAnotherController() {
        let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ControllerForPresentId") as! ControllerForPresent
        vc.present(from: self)
     }
 }
```

Also add an identifier "ControllerForPresentId" to controller you want to present.